# Yii2 replace symbol from name

Tags: php, yii2

In yii2, I would like to check for filename.

If this filename consist of any symbol `(.$%-)`, replace it with `_`.
Can you suggest some solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regular expression search and replace:

```
//Perform a regular expression match first
    if(preg_match('/[.$%-]+/', $file_name) == 1)
    {
      //perform regular expression search and replace
       $new_name = preg_replace('/[.$%-]+/', '_', $file_name);

    }
```

Comment: If I use this method, it will replace the . before file extension to _ as well.

Comment: @cristal , True. You could remove the extension first.  `$extension = substr($file_name, strrpos($file_name, '.'));`  The strip off the extension from the file name: `$file_name= substr($file_name, 0, (strlen($file_name) - strlen($extension)));`  ...then  `$new_name .= $extension;`

Comment: Thank you for the solution.
How about if I want to replace all symbol ?

Comment: Replace the regular expression /[.$%-]+/ with /[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/  Read more on regular expressions.